# How do i trigger an event when a toggle buttons state is changed using only code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a toggle button

```
ToggleButton toggleButton
```

and I need a way to set up an event once the state of the toggle is changed and I need to do this only in code, and I would prefer lambda use

something like this(excuse the syntax if it is not 100% correct)

```
toggleButton.OnChangedStateEvent(=> {/*if checked/* Console.WriteLine("Checked");
                                     /*else/* Console.Writeline("Unchecked")}
```

Comment: Which part of the example in the [help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) is unclear? Where are you having problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach handler to `Checked` and `Unchecked` events of `ToggleButton`:

```
toggleButton.Checked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("checked");
toggleButton.Unchecked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("unchecked");
```

you can also check MSDN example for [ToggleButton.Checked Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This needs two parts.  Attach an event handler for click (you can check the state inside)

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

Then, write a function to handle the event.  Keep the parameters as noted here.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
// Add event handler code here.
}
```

You may also find .Checked() and .CheckOnClick to be useful.